# Phonegap how to check if an android device already has any maps application?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, maps

I'm developing an android app using phonegap. Now i would like to open the native map application of the device only if device has any map application, Otherwise i would like to use the google maps api. Now my problem is , If a native map application is already installed in the device then how to check that?

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

if you use the coordinate information instead of the link, phoneGap directs you to google maps app. as follows;

```
<a href="geo:49.672950,-42.234515">Go to Map</a>
```

Comment: Ok. Now what if the device does not have any map application?. I want to use this only if device has map app. Otherwise i want to use google maps api. How can i achieve this using phonegap, jQuery and javascript?

Comment: Oh, ok i see but i dont have any direct solution. Maybe you can check directory of google map app by using file api. [here!](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_file_file.md.html)

And the directory: /Android/data/com.google.android.apps.maps